# Link UIPickerView to NSTimer iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uipickerview, nstimer

I am building an app similar to snapchat where we take a picture or video and then it destructs after a certain amount of time.

I am implementing a UIPicker within the camera module and once the user take a picture they select a time for how long the recipient sees the picture, then the user sends the image that self destructs after 1-10 seconds.

How can I link the UIPicker to the NSTimer which is another class?

```
camera.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *timePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pickerData;


picker data in camera.m file:
interface //
{
 int secs;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pickerData = @[@"1 second", @"2 seconds", @"3 seconds", @"4 seconds", @"5 seconds", @"6 seconds", @" 7 seconds", @" 8 seconds", @" 9 seconds", @" 10 seconds"];

    self.timePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.timePicker.delegate = self;
}

-(long)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(long)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.pickerData.count;
}

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.pickerData[row];
}

 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
            {
               //help here please
            }
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
//goes to select friends page
}
```

image.m file where image is displayed for the user: this image should destruct after the amount of time the user selects from the picker.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(timeout)]) {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7 target:self selector:@selector(timeout)
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

}

[timeout pops to root view]
```

I need to let the user select a time on the picker and then for the image in the image.m file to destruct after that amount of time.

The user take a picture then below the picture is the pickerview the user selects a time and presses next to go to select friends. half of the screen is the picture the other half is the UIPickerView

[image]

Comment: This is difficult to say with that little information about how the two classes are connected. Somehow the `pickerView didSelectRow ...` should update that information in the `image.m`. That is a guess based upon the few lines of code I see here.

Comment: so the picker data (seconds) i would like to link to the NStimer, so what code would we put in did select row method

Comment: @Harry you didn't provide enough information, but I guess  `NSNotificationCenter ` can help, check my answer

Comment: @Aladin please see above i have provided all i have implemented

Comment: do you have a Button of confirmation like `done` after selecting the time ? because `didSelectRow` is fired every time the user scroll the picker

Comment: once the user selects a time on the picker they press next to go to select friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the data to the second view controller, the one displaying the image.
Something like this :

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // leave this empty

}

- (void)buttonHandler:(UIButton *)sender {
    image *iVC = [[image alloc] init];
    iVC.seconds = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    [self presentViewController:iVC animated:YES];
}
```

And in `ImageViewController.h` you'd need something like this :

```
@interface image : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger seconds;

@end
```

Then just use the value passed in `seconds` property to time your timer in `viewDidLoad` in `camera.m`

Comment: i have added all i have implemented above

Comment: Edited - everything you need is there.

Comment: `didSelectRow` is fired every time the user scroll the picker, as soon as the user scroll to 2 seconds you will present `ImageViewController`

Comment: the user takes a picture then selects time on picker below the image and presses next to select friends

Comment: this answer should works but move the code to the action of the "next" button and get the selected value from the picker, also my answer is still valid if you want to inform and send the amount of seconds to more than a view controller

Comment: thanks guys, i am very new to ios development image *iVC = [[image alloc] init];
    iVC.seconds = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    [self presentViewController:iVC animated:YES]; should i put this code in the IBAction next method? also why do i presentviewcontroller when the UIPicker is displayed below the image? half of the screen is the image other half is UIpicker

Comment: Yes, move it to the IBAction. As for presenting the View Controllers - you didn't show your `*.h` files, and I should have asked for them in the first place :) But the `image.m` file has `viewDidAppear` implemented, and it is a method from `UIViewController` so I just jumped to assumptions and conclussions.

Comment: but if the UIPicker is already on the screen below the image should i still present view controller?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your the UI where the picker and the image are located

Comment: @aladin please see screenshot above

Comment: So I assume the you managed to get the image from the camera roll, and you you will let the user choose the duration from the picker and then click "next", what should happens once the user tap "next" which view you want to present ? what changes in the user interface you want to do ?

Comment: when the user taps next the go to selectfriends. then they send the image to a friend the friend opens image and it destructs after the time the user chose so between 1-10seconds

Comment: This is not something that can be understood from the question ;) it seems that you need to save the data (image and time) and send it to your server. Then send push notifications to selected users and present them the image.

Comment: @Losiowaty any idea how i can do that? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some :) Unfortunatelly it is way beyond the scope of this question. I'd suggest you read about webservices, REST, making url requests with ios. If you bump into other problems, There are some great tutorials out there (for example, this page http://www.raywenderlich.com/ has lots of them).

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just present the image view controller once the user select the the duration from the picker and pass the value of seconds as property of the destination view controller . [check Losiowaty answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31591179/1836115)

If you have a special case for example the view controller that you want to inform is already created and it's not your current view controller that is responsible of creating and presenting it then `NSNotificationCenter` will inform any object that has registered to observe the notification of selecting and sending the photo. We can create a notification called for example `didSendPhoto` and any object can observe and receive a notification once a user send a photo, we an pass data also in our case the duration.

> An NSNotificationCenter object (or simply, notification center)
>   provides a mechanism for broadcasting information within a program. An
>   NSNotificationCenter object is essentially a notification dispatch
>   table.

[NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)

So When the user select the amount of time and send the image you post a notification with the duration as `userInfo`

```
 // instead 50 put the choice of the user from the picker 
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@(50) forKey:@"durationBySeconds"];
 // post the notification 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"didSendPhoto"
                                                    object:nil
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
```

Now from where you want to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`  add observer for the notification previously created

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didSendImage:)
                                             name:@"didSendPhoto"
                                           object:nil];
```

then implement the method

```
-(void) didAddReview:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSNumber *seconds = (NSNumber *)[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"durationBySeconds"];


  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:  [seconds integerValue]
                         target:self
                       selector:@selector(timeout)
                       userInfo:nil
                        repeats:NO];
     [timeout method pops to rootview]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take property for storing the selected value from picker view

camera.h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

say at AppDelegate

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int secondsValue;
```

camera.m

ViewDidLoad Method

```
appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
       //help here please
       appDelegate.secondsValue=(int)[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row];

    }
```

image.h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

image.m

```
appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];



[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:appDelegate.secondsValue
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(timeout)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:NO];
```

This can link Picker View selection to NSTimer..!
Hope it helps you..!

Comment: Passing a value between view controllers through AppDelegate is a bad idea and it shouldn't be done that way. It is not what AppDelegate is for.

Comment: Above way is useful if u want to pass data between two irrelevant views..
He did not gave info about the camera and image objects he is using. So, I have answered that way. He can use that idea with property taken inside his view instead of AppDelegate also..!

Comment: isn't `NSNotificationCenter` better than passing data between view controllers through `AppDelegate`  ?

Comment: May be..its Better. But think this way is easy to understand rather than using NSNotificationCenter...

Comment: Yes but learning bad codeing habits is much, much worse. It reduces code quality and increases the maintenance cost.